# Using HttpClient to download file in UWP

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I want to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient) to download reasonably large files (about 200MB) and I can't use `BackgroundDownloader`. Unfortunately, the documentation seems to imply that I have to download the whole file **in memory** before writing it to the disk. Is there any way to write the files in chunk as the download progresses with `HttpClient`?

Comment: Some questions for this scenario. Hmmm, why a backgrounddownloader cannot be used? Also I only see the following: "If an app using HttpClient and related classes in the Windows.Web.Http namespace downloads large amounts of data (50 megabytes or more), then the app should stream those downloads and not use the default buffering. If the default buffering is used the client memory usage will get very large, potentially resulting in reduced performance." Where did you see that it should download the whole file in memory?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT There are authentication requirements so no backgrounddownloader. Where can I learn how to **stream those downloads and not use the default buffering**?

Comment: I cannot find a C++/Winrt Sample. But you can check C# code to understand the basic first, here is a demo from official sample in C#  https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/HttpClient/cs/Scenario2_GetStream.xaml.cs#L81 In general, you are working with ReadAsInputStreamAsync here.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Thanks for the reference. I didn't know that we can stream the content ourselves.